# SP to populate data as Column store style

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have that stores data in the usual way .

```
Id  | Name | Number
----+------+-------
 1    A      101
 2    B      102
 3    A      103
 4    A      105
 5    C      104
 6    B      106
 7    C      108
```

and so on.

Now I want to convert this table to something similar to column store.
For example all the facility should be ordered and grouped by the name.
Also if a new record arrives with the same the same Name, if should by assigned an ID, which is in the range assigned for that  name group.

Just to elaborate. If 'A' has a ID range from 1 to 20 and currently in the table there are 5 ids, so when a new record arrives with Name A, it should be assigned the ID  = 6.

Name goes with other names. Every time a ID is populates, the NextID in metatable has to incremented by 1.

As of now I have created a meta table which stores the Min, max ID along with next ID for each name group.

**MetaTable**

```
Name  MinID  MaxId  NextID 
---------------------------
  A     1      30      6   
  B    31      60     45   
  C    61     100     78
```

And using case statements to populate the data in the mail Table.  But its very inefficient and the query is long running.

Note: The Number column does not matter.

What could be a more efficient and faster way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to be more elaborate with your question. Provide us with schema sample input and desired output...

Comment: The Input is the first table as show above. The Output would be a table:

Comment: Doesnt the soln I posted help u?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, 
       MIN( ID ),
       MAX( ID ), 
       COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ) + 1 AS NextID
 FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ) + 1 AS NextID populated all the ID's as 2.

Comment: Its supposed to be max(id) +1